# git apply stash without index number

Tags: git

Is there a way by which I can apply stash using its name?  I got list of stashes as below and I would like to apply stash@{0}.

```
stash@{0}: On support.1.5: NoGoMod
stash@{1}: On feature/WORK-7929: 6Aug
stash@{2}: On support.1.5: 17Jul
stash@{3}: On WORK-7739: temp
```

I can apply it with its its index number like (`git stash apply "stash@{0}"`), however is there a way I can apply it with its name... for eg. git stash apply "stash@{NoGoMod}" or something similar to it?

Issue I am facing is the index number changes with every new stash I create.  So if a new stash is added, the list will look something like below

```
stash@{0}: On support.1.5: NewStash
stash@{1}: On support.1.5: NoGoMod
stash@{2}: On feature/WORK-7929: 6Aug
stash@{3}: On support.1.5: 17Jul
stash@{4}: On WORK-7739: temp
```

If stash cant be applied with its name then is there any way I can keep its index number constant?  Is there a way by which new stash gets added to bottom of the list and my existing stash index number does not change?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stash entry is a special ref that points to a commit. So you can simply tag the commit.

```
# after "git stash", tag the last entry
git tag foo stash@{0}

# later use the tag name
git stash apply foo
```

You can make an alias or bash function to combine `git stash` and `git tag`.

With the tag, there are some more advantages for rare cases.

1. The stash entry still exists even if it's been removed or popped from the stash stack. With the tag, you can easily apply it with `git stash apply foo`.
2. You can push the tag to other repositories so that the stash entry can be applied there.

Answer (score 3):

The list of stashes is a *stack*. That means that every new stash is "pushed" onto the stack. So no, there is no way to prevent the numbering change; the most recent stash is always number zero, by the very definition of a stack.

The stash does not have a "name" any more than the message you include with a commit is its "name". A commit is uniquely identified by a name if a branch or tag happens to point to it; otherwise, it is identified by its SHA identification number. Similarly, a stash in the stack of stashes is identified by its place in the stack.

(I am tempted to add: If you don't like that, don't use stashes. In my view, stashes are the work of the devil. They should not be used for temporary storage of the state of a branch; that is what a *commit* is for. If you want to say "hold my place", make a temporary branch and *commit*. Now you have something with a name that you can always come back to. Stashes are only for emergency situations where the index differs from the work tree and there is no time to resolve that, so you need to save the state of the work tree separately from the index.)